# Repetition with Raphael.js Animation Uses More and More CPU Time

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, raphael

Is there a way continuous animation with Raphael.js without the cpu time continuing to grow?

I've tried both .repeat (Infinity) and single and dual callback functions. .repeat (Infinity) gets to 80% within 100 seconds. Ccallbacks are much better (8 minutes to get to 50%) but CPU time still grows.

See http://jsfiddle.net/edelman/VSAED/ for a sample by someone else that shows this.

```
 var paper = new Raphael('spin', 100, 100);
 var rect = paper.rect(20, 20, 20, 20).attr({fill: '#F00'});
 var anim = Raphael.animation({transform: "r360"}, 2500).repeat(Infinity);
 rect.animate(anim);
```

Here is my example with callbacks.

```
    <script>
        var r_canvas;
        var spinEl;
        $(document).ready (function () {
            r_canvas = Raphael ("displayArea", "200", "200");
        });
        function showArrow (bUseRepeat) {
            r_canvas.clear ();
            var path = "M100,100L100,0";
            spinEl = r_canvas.path (path).attr ({"arrow-end":"classic-wide"});
            if (bUseRepeat)
                Raphael.animation ({transform: "...r360, 100,100"}, 2000).repeat (Infinity);
            else
                spin ();
        };
        function spin () {
            spinEl.stop ();
            var spinSpec = Raphael.animation ({transform: "...r360, 100,100"}, 2000, respin);
            spinEl.animate (spinSpec);
        };
        function respin () {
            spinEl.stop ();
            var spinSpec = Raphael.animation ({transform: "...r360, 100,100"}, 2000, spin);
            spinEl.animate (spinSpec);
        };
        function stopArrow () {
            spinEl.stop ();
        };
    </script>
```

Raphael.js v 2.1.2  FireFox 26.0  Fedora 18

Thanks,
Eldon

Comment: Here are two earlier SO questions that may address your issue: [animation.repeat eats 100% cpu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16925541/simple-raphael-js-animation-which-uses-animation-repeat-eats-100-cpu) and [Gradual animation slowdown...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098456/raphael-gradual-animation-slowdown-with-simple-infinite-animation)